# CSS Background Images - How to set up images stay in the position

Tags: css, image, background

I have set up two background images on showcase side by side. It looks fine when I see it on a full screen but when I change the size of the screen by moving the web browser, the image on the left goes over on the image on the right... so I'd like to know how to set both images moving equally. (means change the size of images equally, not left one goes over on the right image) Thank you very much for your help.

```
#showcase{
    min-height: 400px;
    background: url("../IMGS/showcase.jpg") left no-repeat, url("../IMGS/showcase2.jpg") right no-repeat;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: try background-size:50% 100% or background-size:50% auto

Comment: Thank you for your reply but neither of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `/ 50%` exactly after the `background-position` property which in this case is `left` or `right` for either of the images.

you can see the css block as follows:

```
#showcase{
    min-height: 400px;
    background: url("../IMGS/showcase.jpg") left / 50% no-repeat, url("../IMGS/showcase2.jpg") right / 50% no-repeat;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

You can read more and experiment with the property at the MDN Web Docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score 0):

You may have to individually style each image to "width: 50vw;" that will set each of them to occupy 50% of the view-port no matter the size of the window. So they should each change dynamically and adjust by the same size when the window increases or decreases.